# php avatar image and real image display

Tags: php, mysqli

I am creating PHP products view page. I want to display products uploaded by user profile pic and if not updated user real image should be displayed avatar image. My script is working but not showing avatar image I have tried to make but it's not working

Here is my code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['srcid'])) {
        $srcid = $_GET['srcid'];
        if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT p.*,c.cat_title,u.username,u.profile_pic,title,desc1,time,img,img1,img2,img3,views,id FROM products AS p 
            JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id= p.user_id
            JOIN category AS c ON c.cat_id = p.cat_id
            WHERE id=?")){
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $srcid);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
    }
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

?>

<div class="article">
<?php
    $profile_pic = $row['profile_pic']; 
    if ($profile_pic == '') {
?>

<img src="user/icons/avatar.png " width="100" height="100"  style=" margin-top:-20px; float:left;"/>    

<?php
    }else{
?>

<img src='user/profile_picture/<?php echo  $row['profile_pic'];?>' width='150px' height='130px'  style=' float:left;  border:0px solid #ddd'>
<font color="#f90" style="padding:3px;font-family: 'Oswald';">ARTICLE POSTED BY:</font><a href="profile.php?u=<?php echo  $row['username'];?>"><?php echo  $row['username'];?></a></div>
<p class="v-p1"></p>
<?php 
            }
        }
    }
?>
<div class="uploaded"></div>
```

Comment: Have you checked that the relativ image path is correct and access able from your current URL? Look in your HTML source code.

Comment: not showing avatar image please help me

Comment: Check your relative image path. Could you access your image from your current code page, manuel? When you are debugging your $row variable, is there a value inside? Try to use an absolute path to your image.

Comment: i am not understanding can you edit and show me?

Comment: Debug your $row variable and post it as an edit on your question. like @venom_1979 wrote as comment.

Answer (score 0):

null does not always equal '';

try `if (strlen(trim($profile_pic)) == 0) {?>`

Comment: can you look at the output to see if the the src is `user/icons/avatar.png` or something else  there is a space after the avatar.png which may also cause an issue.

Comment: like this <img src="user/icons/avatar.png"width="100" height="100"  style=" margin-top:-20px; float:left;"/>

Comment: in that case the logic is working , check if html image is  correct.

Comment: please anyone can help me

Answer (score 0):

Try var dumping $profile_pic to see what it's contents are, or use empty() instead:

```
<?php if(empty($profile_pic)) { ?>
```

This way you're covered whether it's NULL, 0, false or an empty string.

Also, check your image path to make sure it's working. You're currently using a relative path to the image, maybe try the full URL instead just in case.

Comment: What was the result from your `var_dump($row['profile_pic'])`? This would help to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: but getting same results